# how to resolve datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

what's problem in my datepicker,datepicker can't show required when field empty.i try submit button datepicker can't show

```html
<form  class="form-horizontal" id="activity" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>input_activity/submit">
<div class="input-group date date-picker" id="dpDOB" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control" readonly name="start" required> //datepicker
<button type="submit" class="btn green">
<i class="fa fa-save"></i> submit</button>

</form>
  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function() {          
  $('#activity').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap', 
    fields: {                                     
    start: {
        validators: {
           notEmpty: {
          message: 'startdate is required and cannot be empty'
           },
           date: {
          message: 'The value is not a valid date',
          format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'
           }
        }
    },//dob                     
    }//fields
  });           
});
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
$('#dpDOB').datepicker({
 format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
})
.on('changeDate', function(e) {
// Revalidate the date field
   $('#activity').formValidation('revalidateField', 'dob');
});
</script>
```

can you give me great js datepicker?

Comment: I suggest you to use bootstrap datepicker. Here is the link 
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: yes i use bootsrap datepicker,but how to validate datepicker can not be empty?

Comment: Did you use required attribute in input tag?